# In a Kendo jQuery grid how can you identify which rows are displayed to the user?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, grid

I have a kendo jquery grid that has a data source with hundreds of records. The grid is paged (50,100...). However, the the grid only takes up a small amount of space on the web page and therefore the horizontal scroll is there. Lets say there are only 25 of the 100 rows per page that are visible to the user given the current size of the page. How can you determine which 25 rows are currently in the view port of the grid that the user can see?

Please note I am not asking about the rows that are a part of the dataSource.view (which would be 100 in this case). I am looking for the 25 subset of that 100 that is viewable.

Comment: [Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/how-to-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling), but what exactly are you trying to do? I'm sensing the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) might apply here.

Comment: Looks promising. Thanks